# F# Private Static Methods

Tags: f#, static, methods, declaration

How do i define a private static method in a class in f#? when i try to attach a private modifier it complains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a short script that defines and uses a private static member:

```
type MyClass =
    static member private MyPrivateMember() = printfn "MyPrivateMember()"

    static member MyMember() = MyClass.MyPrivateMember()

MyClass.MyMember() // MyPrivateMember()
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative:

```
type MyClass () =
    static let myPrivateMethod () =
        printfn "This is inaccessible outside the class."
```